# Modbus commands within node.js

Tags: node.js, modbus

I'm new here and try to build my webaplication with node.js to read and write modbus data from a door operator.

So far I have successfully used modbus-serial package to send and receive data with function code 3 and 16.

```
var ModbusRTU = require("modbus-serial");
var client = new ModbusRTU();
client.connectRTUBuffered("/dev/ttyUSB0", { baudRate : 9600, dataBits : 8, stopBits : 1, parity : "none", });
client.setID(2);

    socket.on('op_mode', function (data, err) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('op_mode : ' + data);
            client.writeRegisters(20, [data, 0]); //data is a number between 1 and 6
        }
    });
```

This represents the equivalent of typing "2 16 0 20 0 2 4 0 2 0 0" into Realterm on Windows.

With "2 3 0 20 0 2" I'm able to read data with Realterm. An the equivalent in node.js is:

```
client.readHoldingRegisters(20, 2, function(err, data) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Reg 20: ' + data.data[0]);
    }
});
```

Now I need to send the command "2 100 252 249 0 0" with node.js which I don't know how to do as the function code 100 is not present. The same command in Realterm is working fine.

For me it would also be ok to use the SerialPort package but need some help to get the code right to receive an answer from my operator.

Thanks in advance.

Additional information from 08.02.2021

Message information from documentation:

Slave address Byte 0 = 2

Function code Byte 1 = 100

Byte 2 = 252

Byte 3 = 249

Byte 4 = 0

Byte 5 = 0

Modbus16 CRC must be added. Response has the same structure.

Comment: Function code 100 is a "User-Defined Function Code" (see the [modbus spec](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf)). Because user defined functions are not standardised the data sent/received will depend upon the implementation (device/manufacturer specific). This means you will need to locate a package that supports your devices implementation or write this yourself (the packet structure should be covered in the device documentation - if you provide further info we may be able to locate this).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response. I will post additional information in my Question.

Comment: OK - not sure what your question is then? You will need to write this yourself; I'd suggest forking the repo and using [writeFC4](https://github.com/yaacov/node-modbus-serial/blob/master/index.js#L664) as a starting point (you will also need to update the appropriate [port](https://github.com/yaacov/node-modbus-serial/blob/master/ports/rtubufferedport.js#L193)).